# Sending mail using mail gem and smtp delivery method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to send a mail using smtp method whose configration i had done in **development.rb** file,here it is

```
    Rails.application.configure do
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
      config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
       address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
       port:                 587,
       domain:               'example.com',
       user_name:            'angad1@gmail.com',
       password:             xxxxxxxx,
       authentication:       'plain',
       enable_starttls_auto: true  
    }
```

Here is the UserMailer which is present under the mailers folder, here i am getting the parameters value from a controller and parameter is assigned to a varible ,so that it can be available to the view
    **UserMailer.rb**

```
    class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
        default from: 'angad1@gmail.com'
        layout 'mailer'
        def conference_result(email,proposal,acknowledgement,positive,negative,chart)
            @email = email
            @proposal = proposal
            @acknowledgement = acknowledgement
            @positive = positive
            @negative = negative
            @chart = chart
            mail(to: @email , subject: 'Result for Your conference meeting' , content_type: "text/html")
        end
    end
```

Here is the content which i want to deliver in the mail,
    **mailer.html.erb**

```
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
            <h3 class="text-center" id="proposalhead">Proposal</h3>
            <div style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" class="text-center">
                <%= @proposal %>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center hidden" id ="acknowledgementhead">Acknowledgement</h3>
            <div style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;" id ="Acknowledgement" class="text-center">
                <%= @acknowledgement %>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center hidden" id ="positivehead">Positive</h3>
            <div style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;" id ="Positive" class="text-center">
                <%= @positive %>
            </div>
            <h3 class="text-center hidden" id ="negativehead">Negative</h3>
            <div style="border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:20px" id = "Negative" class="text-center">
                <%= @negative %>
            </div>
            <div id="chart_div" style="width:100%;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top:15px;" class="text-center">
                <%= @chart %>
            </div>      
      </body>
```

When i trying to send the mail, it is showing following error

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template user_mailer/conference_result with "mailer". Searched in:* "user_mailer")

Please help me out,i am new to ruby .

Comment: Is there a conference_result email template in the `user_mailer` forlder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error says, **Missing template user_mailer/conference_result**.

You need to create a template `app/views/user_mailer/conference_result.html.erb`

Comment: Thank you for your help,gmail is sending a mail but it the mail,Google just blocked someone from signing into your Google Account . How to overcome this.

Comment: go here with your account logged in and enable access to less secure apps https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: Thank you,i had done it.The content which i am sending is not geeting displayed in a proper format.I am getting something like this in mail                        ---==_mimepart_5940e1d369d8f_282d2658644331d6 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit ----==_mimepart_5940e1d369d8f_282d2658644331d6 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Comment: Angad: Yes, he should have. Leave all this, how is your projects going= on?<br>Tej: yes<br>Tej: yes i agree with angad.<br>

Comment: what you see in email entirely depends on the view you create. you should not ask multiple questions on same/irrelevant posts. You are welcome to create another question :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the mail template itself. If you haven't got it, that explains the error - Otherwise I'd make sure it's in the right folder, probably `app/views/user_mailer/conference_result.html.erb` and `.text.erb`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.Gmail is sending a mail but  the mail containing,Google just blocked someone from signing into your Google Account . How to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

```
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps
```

login your email then open above link.
enable lesssecure app.